# VueJS - Communicating from child component to parent not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm in the beginning stages of learning VueJS and am building a quick and dirty 'todo' list to get a hold of the basics.

For some reason I'm having trouble raising an event in a child component and then having the parent component respond to that event, I've followed the documentation for emitting an event in the child and then binding to it in the parent with:

`v-on:my-event=""`

Etc... but the event is never run on the parent component.

Example child component:

```
var todoHeader = {
    template: `<nav><button v-on:click="switchView('list')">View List</button><button v-on:click="switchView('add')">Add Todo</button></nav>`,
    methods: {
        switchView: function(view) {
            this.$emit('switch-view', view)
        }
    }
};
```

Example parent which listens to the `switch-view` event being raised:

```
Vue.component('todo-list', {
   data: function() {
   return {
       currentView: ''
   }
},
components: {
  'todo-header': todoHeader,
  'list-todos': listTodos,
  'add-todo': addTodo
},
template: 
   `<div v-on:switch-view="onSwitchView"><todo-header></todo-header>
   <list-todos></list-todos>
   <add-todo></add-todo></div>`,
methods: {
   onSwitchView: function(view) {
       console.log(view);
   }
}
});
```

I should be seeing the selected view being logged to the console but I get nothing, can anyone see what I've done wrong? My intention is to have a navigation bar with two buttons for controlling the current view, either list or add mode. The child add/list components would listen to this value and toggle accordingly.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3sp4k0gf/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put the event listeners on the child component's custom tag:

```
template: 
   `<div>
        <todo-header v-on:switch-view="onSwitchView"></todo-header>
        <list-todos></list-todos>
        <add-todo></add-todo>
    </div>`,
```

Fixed [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3sp4k0gf/7/)

Comment: You beat me to it! I believe this is it as well! +1

Comment: Yep, I think this was it. Check the jsfiddle

Comment: Hah, nem vi q era br hue! Mas dá nada, o que tá certo, tá certo, ora! :D

Comment: Perfect, can you explain why they need to be on the child components tag and why it didn't work before? Thanks

Comment: Because the tag is basically where you define the instance of that component. And the instance is the one emitting the events. So, the tag is the one that should receive the events from the component. The parent div (where you were putting it) had nothing to do with the child component.

Comment: @Phiter Thanks, that makes sense, I figured it was something like that